# How does dmenu_run work?

Tags: shell-script, shell, dmenu

My system is `Debian 9.4` which uses `linux kernel 4.9.0-8-amd64` and `echo $SHELL` on my system gives `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/dash`.

I was curious why every time I run an application with `dmenu_run` from `dwm` there is an additional `/bin/bash` process that runs as the parent, so I dug further into the script of `dmenu_run`:

```
#!/bin/sh
dmenu_path | dmenu "$@" | ${SHELL:-"/bin/sh"} &
```

I can't understand why my computer has `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`. I also read the correspond source code in `dwm`. It shows that it just simply `fork` and `execvp` `dmenu_run`. There is no reason for `/bin/bash` to run instead of `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash` in systems that use `bash` as the default shell.